# Integrating cmake project into bazel monorepo

Tags: c++, cmake, bazel, build-system, bazel-cpp

I'm playing around with bazel (rather new to it) and want to integrate one of my projects that needs to use cmake due to the use of JUCE.

I built a minimal example but I'm getting the error:
`BUILD.bazel:5:6: output 'cmake_test/projectA/helloworldexec' was not created`

my folder structure is

```
cmake_test
  projectA
    src
      helloworld.cpp
    BUILD.bazel
    CMakeLists.txt
  BUILD.bazel
WORKSPACE.bazel
```

WORKSPACE.bazel basically just sets up rules_foreign_cc

cmake_test/BUILD:

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:build_test.bzl", "build_test")
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_test")
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cmake(
    name = "projectA",
    generate_args = ["-GNinja"],
    lib_source = "//cmake_test/projectA:a_srcs",
    out_binaries = ["helloworldexec"],
    out_bin_dir = ""
)
```

cmake_test/projectA/BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

filegroup(
    name = "a_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.23.0)

project(helloworld)

add_executable(helloworldexec src/helloworld.cpp)
```

helloworld.cpp is just a main function that couts hello world.

Why isn't this built?

Comment: Would go for a pure Bazel approach without CMake -> https://github.com/chetgnegy/bazel_juce